# Why EGL context is related to only one Thread

Tags: android, opengl-es, gpu, opencl, egl

I am a little bit confused by the EGL CONTEXT meaning Specially using 3D in GPU.

Thread are on the CPU side. Each thread can send command to the GPU to execute an Object drawing(vertice,texture, exct... using shader)

Each shader are related to one program ans can use or not what has been defined in the shader. For this we need to bind the ressource before draw array or elements.

I considere that i send every ressources to the GPU at initialisation, except camera frame, which is differnte. If i considere that on mobile, meromry is shared between CPU and GPU. What the need of defining a context by thread. Is explain what i do not anderstand.

If a need to execute a shader and use some ressources i do not need to context. I just need to bind the right ressource for the right program shader. Any thread could do it as long as it is done one by one. Has memory is common any thread could acces any ressources on the GPU, one by one of course. Or may be on differente channel of GPU receiver so too program(shader) could be procces in parralelle.

So no need to allocate ressource to context. All ressouce should be accessible by référence. Has drawwing i done by program(shader) one simple call (program, ressouce1,ressource2, ext) would be enought.

So why one context per thraed. there is flexibility. No need to share context anymore witch does not work, for me. Any shader could use any ressource exct...

I really do not anderstant why EGL context and even less why thread related.

Thanks in advance for the explanation.

PS: i create this question bacause it is a nightmare to share texture between JAVA EGL (thread + context) and thread in C++ using OpenCL. I really do not anderstand the mess accessing resource like texture or vertice. It should be simple by référence.

Answer (score 0):

> I really do not understand why EGL context and even less why thread related

... because that's what the specification says. Ultimately, it doesn't matter if you disagree with the design, the specification works a particular way and that's how it works.

You can allocate multiple EGL contexts in the same sharegroup - this allows some form of data sharing from parallel threads (but state is still context local). This is commonly used for one context being a background loader thread, while another does the actual rendering.

Newer APIs, like Vulkan, still have contexts but lose the threading restrictions.

Comment: You seem to be wanting something that doesn't exist. EGL has contexts. Contexts have threading restrictions. That's just the way it is.

Comment: I give out talking about reason why. I just want things to work. So could you please explain me what should i do to be able to use EGLImageKHR in my C++ and be able to use the GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES and my JAVA part application. Is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

The EGL context is the main connection between your CPU and GPU.  When they restrict the EGL context to be attached to one CPU thread at a time, they ensure that the requests from the CPU to the GPU will come in a well defined order.  They want to avoid situations where multiple CPU threads are talking to the GPU at the same time, and in an unpredictable order.

In your example, you assert that your resources are bound "1 by 1".  If this is the case, then it should be OK for the EGL context to be bound/rebound to one CPU thread at a time.  This can be accomplished by calls to eglMakeCurrent.

If, however, you cannot guarantee that your operations are "well ordered", then that is a problem you need to work out -- regardless of what EGL supports.